# Почему значение value в input не заполняется значением из vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Задача сделать чтобы значение введённое в **input** сохранялось при вводе во **vuex** и уже во **vuex** сохранялось в **localstorage** ,а потом если приложение было закрыто, то при повторном открытии значение сохранённое в **localstorage** должно вывестись обратно в **input**. 
Сейчас у меня вводимое значение почему-то не сохраняется.
Подскажите пожалуйста ,что я делаю не так или по возможности поправьте код. Спасибо!

**Сам компонент**

```
<f7-list-input
  placeholder="Username"
  type="text"
  v-bind:value="name"
  @input="onPersist"
/>

export default {
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.name) {
    this.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
        }
    },

computed:{
    name(){
        return this.$store.state.name;
    }
},
methods:{
    onPersist(){
        this.$store.commit('persist',event.target.value);
    }
}
    };
    </script>
```

**хранилище VUEX**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        name: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        persist(state,payload){
        state.name = payload; 
        localStorage.setItem('name', state.name);
       },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Писать из свойства компонента в хранилище можно используя геттеры/сеттеры.

Проверить с `localStorage` можно здесь https://jsfiddle.net/v3b28j5m/1/

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    name: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    persist(state, payload) {
      state.name = payload;
      console.log(payload)
      //localStorage.setItem('name', state.name);
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    name: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.name;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setValue(e) {
      this.$store.commit('persist', e.target.value);
    }
  },
  created() {
    //this.$store.state.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.0/vuex.min.js">
</script>

<div id="app">
  <input placeholder="Username" type="text" :value="name" @input="setValue" />
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в том ,что мне нужно сделать это именно при помощи framework7 ,а в нем v-model не поддерживается по этому я делаю через v-bind:value и @input ,но почему-то через них не могу записать значение во vuex и вернуть его. Уже две недели мучаюсь с решением.

Comment: Не вижу проблемы использовать ваш вариант. Ответ обновил.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.